# Trouble with selecting node with querySelector using data attribute values

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors

I have 9 divs in my html like so:

```html
    <div class="game-cell" data-row="1" data-column="1"></div>
    <div class="game-cell" data-row="1" data-column="2"></div>
    <div class="game-cell" data-row="1" data-column="3"></div>
    <div class="game-cell" data-row="2" data-column="1"></div>
    <div class="game-cell" data-row="2" data-column="2"></div>
    <div class="game-cell" data-row="2" data-column="3"></div>
    <div class="game-cell" data-row="3" data-column="1"></div>
    <div class="game-cell" data-row="3" data-column="2"></div>
    <div class="game-cell" data-row="3" data-column="3"></div>
```

I am trying to select one of them at a time using

```js
document.querySelector(`.game-cell, [data-row="1"], [data-column="2"]`)
```

but on printing the output the node that get selected is the one with row and column values 1, no matter what values i specify:

```js
<div class="game-cell" data-row="1" data-column="1">
```

Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong? How can I select the node I want?

Comment: In a CSS selector the `,` means **or**. Your selector currently says: give me the first element that has either the CSS class `game-cell` **OR** that has the attribute `data-row="1"` **OR** that has the attribute `data-column="2"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the columns:

```
document.querySelector('.game-cell[data-row="1"][data-column="2"]');
```

An alternative:

```
let myelement;
document.querySelectorAll('.game-cell').forEach(cell => () { 
  myrow = cell.dataset.row;
  mycolumn = cell.dataset.column;
  if (myrow == x && mycolumn == y) { //you specify 'x' and 'y'
    myelement = cell;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a selector to match all elements with the 'game-cell' class so that you can then filter the results based on their row and column attributes using pure js :

```
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.game-cell');
const targetCell = Array.from(cells).find(cell => 
  cell.getAttribute('data-row') === '1' && cell.getAttribute('data-column') === '2'
);
```